# Is there a word that sounds similar to “titbit”?

Tags: word-request

I’m sure that I’ve came across the word that sounds or spells similar to **titbit** or **tipbit**, and has the meaning of “*key point*” or “*focus*” or “*essential part*”.
For example:

> The **titbit** of his idea is to gather as many trusted people as possible.
>
> The **titbit** is for you to see it for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're thinking of ["tidbit" (AmE) or "titbit" (BrE)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/titbit), but this does not mean "essential part".  It means, either, *"a small piece of tasty food"* or *"a small and particularly interesting item of gossip or information."*

Example:

> Here's an interesting **tidbit** for you: both my grandparents fought in World War II, in the same battle, but on opposite sides.

Words that do mean "essential point":  *crux, gist, nub, pith, meat, nitty-gritty, core, kernel, bottom line,* and several others.

Comment: Yes, that’s it, the word I’m looking for—tidbit(BRE titbit). I was wrong about the meaning.